# Setting the property as disabled="true" in template using jquery.

Tags: jquery, html

I disabled the div element in jquery using `$("#divid").attr("disabled",true);`
It is setting `disabled="disabled"` in the template.I want the property as `disabled="true"` in the template.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this at the DOM level, you cannot and should not.

`disabled` is the only acceptable value for the `disabled` attribute in HTML.

> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes

In theory, you could serialise to HTML and then perform string manipulation of it to change the value of the attribute to one that is invalid … but don't do that.

(NB: Div elements are not among those which have a disabled [attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1)).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use another value than [`disabled` for the `disabled` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute). The `disabled` attribute is a boolean attribute and so:

> **Note:** The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

However, you can create your own attribute, prefixed by `data-` and use it:

```
$("#divid").data("disabled", false);  // will add an attr data-disabled equal to false
```

See the [jQuery.data() method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

disabled attribute is not support in DIV elements. how about adding a class="disabled" ?